# jQuery cannot read property closest of null

Tags: jquery

I am using the same script on all pages but it fails on just one. The error log states "cannot read property closest of null" and highlights the very first line. Cannot see any reason why it would work on all pages bar one so would be grateful if anyone could shed some light on this issue?

```
$("ul.menu").closest(".dropdown_fullwidth").add('ul.menu li').add('ul.nav-shop').mouseenter(function () {
    $("#nav-blackout").css("display", "block");
})
    $("ul.menu").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#nav-blackout").css("display", "none");
});
    $("ul.menu").mouseenter(function () {
    $("ul.nav-shop li:nth-child(1)").addClass("is-active");
    $("li.is-active a").next(".has-product-noms").addClass("display-product-noms"); 
    if ($(".display-product-noms")[0]){
    $(".nav-banner").css("right", "0");
} else {
    $(".nav-banner").css("right", "9999em");
}
})
    $("ul.menu").mouseleave(function () {
    $("ul.nav-shop li:nth-child(1)").addClass("is-active");
    $("li.is-active a").next(".has-product-noms").addClass("display-product-noms"); 
});
    $("li.nav-shop-sub").mouseenter(function () {
    $("li.nav-shop-sub .is-active").removeClass("is-active");
    $(this).addClass("is-active");
    $("li.is-active a").next(".has-product-noms").addClass("display-product-noms");
    if ($(".display-product-noms")[0]){
    $(".nav-banner").css("right", "0");
} else {
    $(".nav-banner").css("right", "9999em");
}
    $("#nav-blackout").css("display", "block");
})
    $("li.nav-shop-sub").mouseleave(function () {
    $("li.is-active a").next(".has-product-noms").removeClass("display-product-noms");
    $(this).removeClass("is-active");
    $("#nav-blackout").css("display", "none");
});
    $(".menu").tinyNav();
});
```

Comment: cause there's no `ul` element with the `menu`class on that page ?

Comment: @Bartdude It wouldn't throw an error.

Comment: Are you sure that in this page, `$ === jQuery`?

Comment: @Bartdude definitely a UL element as its the same navigation code used on every page

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon changed the $ to jQuery and problem solved! Thank you